# Oracle procedure doesn't return to Java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a Java code using oracle-jdbc-driver-12.1.0.2.0 to connect in oracle 11g database. I'm using `CallableStatement` to call procedures. However, some procedures finish in database but don't return to Java.

I created this procedure to test:

```
create or replace procedure pSleep (pSleepInMinutes NUMBER)
as
  vNow DATE := SYSDATE;
begin
  --
  procLog.info('INIT' || to_char(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
  --
  dbms_output.put_line('START: ' || to_char(vNow,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
  --
  loop
    exit when vNow + (pSleepInMinutes * (1/1440)) <= SYSDATE;
  end loop;
  --
  procLog.info('END' || to_char(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
  --
  commit;
  --
  dbms_output.put_line('FINISH: ' || to_char(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
end;
/
```

This is the Java code to execute the procedure:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@100.100.00.000:1521:database11g", "pass", "pass");
connection.setAutoCommit(true);

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
try {
        stmt.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN'");
        stmt.execute("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'AMERICA'");
} finally {
    stmt.close();
}
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{call MYGRANT.pSleep(?)}");
cs.setInt(1, 180);
cs.execute();
```

If the parameter of pSleep is 180 minutes (3 hours) or more, the procedure finishs in database but doesn't return to Java. The program is locked expecting some return. However, It runs properly for 2h or less hours.

Ps: The database is in VirtualBox in my own computer.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Never tried it, but you should try Connection.abort(Executor) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#abort(java.util.concurrent.Executor)

Comment: Is your database session still alive - you can see it finishing (via procLog, I guess)? And the Java side doesn't see any SQLException from the call? Sounds like something on your network is dropping the connection when it's been idle too long. Maybe a firewall between your client and the DB server.

Comment: I'm using the database inseide a virtual box in my own computer. I think it is not network problem.